# Most optimal way to detect multiple timers / countdowns hitting 0?

Tags: java, timer, countdown

I am writing to see what everyone's way of doing this is.

Example:
I have multiple timers with a start time of potentially anything. E.G, One timer could be 30 seconds, the second could be 10 minutes, the third could be 3mins 32seconds, and so on... You can create infinite timer countdowns.

Now, the question is... What's the best way to detect when a timer hits 0? Java does have a runnable class and I was going to run an async task to check every second but this sounds really inefficient to me.

Are there any other ways to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Keep a list of tasks sorted by their start time. Sleep until the next start time. Do the tasks with that start time. Sleep again...

Comment: [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: Just use ScheduledExecutorService, it can manage all this for you